# You can say it again or why not?

Tags: conversation

I'm confused about this dialog I extract from my exam.

> A:Honey,let's eat out tonight. What do you think?
>   B:_____________ I don't feel like cooking anyway.
>   A:Perfect.

1.Not again!
2.You can say it again
3.Why not?
4.Can I take a rain check?
5.You must be kidding me.

I'm wondering I should answer 2 or 3. I can't tell apart their meanings anymore. Could you explain that for me?

Comment: So, you are undecided whether to choose #2 or #3. What is your reasoning/thinking/interpretation of these?

Answer (score -1):

Lets first answer the exam question.

> A:Honey,let's eat out tonight. What do you think?
>   B:_____________ I don't feel like cooking anyway.
>   A:Perfect.

I don't feel like cooking anyway. is negative so we would be looking for a missing positive option.

> 2.You can say it again
>
> 3.Why not?

You can say it again is wrong the phrase is **you can say that again!** [Link C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/you-can-say-that-again)used to show that you completely agree with what someone has said

So the correct answer is **Why not?**

Now I think you will agree that **the difference** between **You can say it again** & **Why not**? is irrelevant.